# How can I identify a type of dance which goes with a specific music?

Tags: rhythm, dance

If I hear a certain piece of music, how can I identify an ideal dance for it?

For example, I would like to assign this [song](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=xifWG50X9dE&pp=ygUrbGVuIGJleiDFvmVueSBtw7TFvmUgYnnFpSDEjWxvdmVrIGJsYcW-ZW7DvQ%3D%3D) to a dance but I do not know how. I am guessing Foxtrot? But that’s just a guess…

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Na niečo také si tancuj s chalanom. :o)) Hej, mne to tiež znie ako foxtrot.

Comment: @Divizna - please note, the preferred language of communication on this site is English!

Comment: @Tim It was a remark that wouldn't make any sense without understanding the lyrics of the song. Then I added "yeah, sounds like a foxtrot to me too", but I'm sure you could guess that one. As you can see below, my answer to the actual question (not just the example) is in English.

Answer (score 2):

Several main things to consider.

The tempi (bpm) of all modern dances are pretty well sacrosanct - they need to be played at a particular speed. Ballroom dancers will know if it's correct.

The *feel* of the piece. Whether it's straight or swung. This will make a big difference to a piece, even if the tempos are the same. Beats within the bar can often be changed to suit -   a song could be adapted to a foxtrot or a tango, by changing the rhythm within each bar to suit, as a rough example.

Another factor which *may* be relevant is the length of the verse. There are some sequence dances which rely on a certain number of bars, before repeating. If that differs from those in the song in question, they will be out of sync as soon as one verse finishes and the next starts.

Of course, some songs will be suitable for changes in the first two factors, but some just don't seem to work.

And there's the obvious *number of beats in the bar*. Foxtrots, cha-chas and quicksteps will need 4, waltzes 3!

Answer (score 1):

My old math teacher's prefered method of solving quadratic equations was "I look and I see". My approach here is along the same line - I listen and I hear. That's a samba. That's a polka. That's a waltz. It helps that songs are often composed, not to mention arranged, with the particular dance in mind. There's a recognisable pattern that you can tell from the patterns of other dances. I couldn't describe any of them in detail but when I hear a song with a strong dancing rhythm, it makes me automatically imagine the corresponding dance.

I said "pattern" because I'm not even sure if it's rhythm in the most detailed sense of the word, or there's also something else to it. But when you hear it, you hear it (kinda like you can tell the taste of orange juice from peach without taking it to a lab for a chemical analysis). For example, you might not exactly expect this from a rock band like the Doors, and on the surface [Wintertime Love](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aUN03rwFYBs) doesn't seem to have that much in common with the [Blue Danube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U7ziPn7lbes), but the dooo-da-ta underneath just makes me swirl in the exact same way. And you might not expect John Lennon of all people to write a

> samba

- but when you hear [Dear Yoko](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n4JQKIYb7L8), don't you just feel it in your knees and shoulders?

If you can feel the music "pushing" you into a particular sequence of steps, chances are those are the right ones. No need to overthink this, let your intuition take the lead.

(If you can't feel the music "pushing" you, then maybe train your intuition with some more experience with dancing? Just make sure you dance to music and not to counting - dancing lessons are actually pretty bad for this, take a good dancing partner to a dance or ball instead to show you in the wild. Or just let her put something on in your living room and... er, how does one say in English, "trsněte si"? "Shake a leg", is that the right phrase?)